# Freeradius doesn't start when CoS user attributes are configured

Tags: authentication, radius, juniper, freeradius, pppoe

I have a problem with a POC, I tried use Freeradius for authentication purpose and assign attributes for users of a broadband network (PPPoE). When I configure the user with this parameters I can connect the PPPoE client in the network and the Freeradius start without problems:

```
user4@lab.com     Cleartext-Password := "Passwd123"
                  ERX-Virtual-Router-Name = "test",
                  ERX-Address-Pool-Name = "FTTH-V4-POOL",
                  ERX-Primary-DNS = 8.8.8.8,
                  ERX-Ingress-Policy-Name = "AB-5M",
                  ERX-Egress-Policy-Name = "AB-5M"
```

However, when I try to add more attributes about CoS, I can't start the Freeradius Server:

> Job for radiusd.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status radiusd.service" and "journalctl
> -xe" for details

systemctl status radiusd.service output:

> ● radiusd.service - FreeRADIUS high performance RADIUS server.
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/radiusd.service; enabled;
> vendor preset: disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since
> lun 2021-07-26 15:20:52 -05; 33s ago   Process: 30884
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/radiusd -d /etc/raddb (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 31061 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/radiusd -C
> (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 31059
> ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R radiusd.radiusd /var/run/radiusd
> (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 30887 (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)

The additional attributes that I try to add are the follow:

```
user4@lab.com     Cleartext-Password := "Passwd123"
                  ERX-Virtual-Router-Name = "test",
                  ERX-Address-Pool-Name = "FTTH-V4-POOL",
                  ERX-Primary-DNS = 8.8.8.8,
                  ERX-Ingress-Policy-Name = "AB-5M",
                  ERX-Egress-Policy-Name = "AB-5M",
                  ERX-CoS-Parameter-Type = "T01 BB-SUB-COS",
                  ERX-CoS-Parameter-Type = "T02 5m",
                  ERX-CoS-Scheduler-Pmt-Type = "SCHEDULER-EF T01 2m",
                  ERX-CoS-Scheduler-Pmt-Type = "SCHEDULER-AF T01 1m",
                  ERX-CoS-Scheduler-Pmt-Type = "SCHEDULER-AF T02 1m",
                  ERX-CoS-Scheduler-Pmt-Type = "SCHEDULER-NC T01 1m",
                  ERX-CoS-Scheduler-Pmt-Type = "SCHEDULER-NC T02 1m"
```

I use a Juniper MX router like BNG. Does anyone know what problem is happening with user settings?